# Call a page-specific function on an opened page

Tags: javascript, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, dom-events

In a Firefox extension I am currently developing using the **addon builder**, I open a page in a new tab and I would like to call a JS function defined in a script on this page. For this I use this code:

```js
var toOpenTab = require("tabs");
toOpenTab.on('open', function(tab){
    toOpenTab.on('ready', function(tab){
        tab.attach({
            contentScript:
                "function showFile(){PageSpecificFunction()};window.onload=showFile();"
        });

    });

});
```

*I implement the window.onload event to be sure that the script containing the PageSpecificFunction() definition is loaded in the page, even though I don't think it is necessary (because I use the toOpenTab.onReady event).*

The problem is: **PageSpecificFunction() is not defined**. I know the function is correctly defined and works fine because I can call it in the firebug console and it works perfectly.

Is there a way to make my extension call this function once my page is opened ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the global `unsafeWindow` object:

`unsafeWindow.PageSpecificFunction();`

[However this is a security risk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.9/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/accessing-the-dom.html)

Comment: I understand the risk. This works perfectly, thank you very much.